# While in runtime, is it possible add an sub-menu item to the tkinter dropdown menu?

Tags: python, tkinter

While in runtime (I mean, while the user operates the application), I would like to know if is it possible, usind Tkinter, add an sub-menu item to an existing menu, and link the new sub-menu to some code.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's possible. Go ahead and try it and see if it works.

Comment: @Kevin, thanks for the fast reply. I know nothing about Tkinter, so I would like to be 100% sure of that before starting to learn it. Why do you feel is it possible?

Comment: I've done it several times to add items in a 'recent files' sub-menu, so I'm 100% sure it is possible. You can add, remove and configure menu items in runtime.